# Installing ZendServer on IIS6

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, zend-server

I need to run ASP and PHP applications side by side, so I installed ZendServer Community Edition on our existing Server 2003 platform.  I specified it to use the existing IIS instance so I don't have to deal with multiple ports (we use ZoneEdit to manage our DNS and they don't seem to allow anything other than port 80 without forwarding).

The install went smooth but when I try to configure and manage the install by going to `http://localhost/ZendServer` (or even just localhost) I get a `Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)` error.

I haven't done anything except install the server, and this is my first time working with ZendServer.

How do I fix this so I can get things set up?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the ZendServer installer put some host header directives in your IIS config that is causing IIS not to direct the requests properly.  Does it work with a non-localhost URL?  Check the host headers on your IIS site(s) and see if there's anything that would be blocking it.